# Writing textbox values to xml file in C#.net

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, textbox

I have two TextBoxes namely `txtUserid` and `txtPassowrd`.

I'm writing the values entered in textboxes to  a `XML` file but I do not want the same `txtuserid` values to be written twice in `XML` - it should be overwritten.

**For example :**

- If I enter in `txtUserid=2` and `txtPassword=I`
- and the second time if I enter `txtUserid=2` and  `txtPassword=m`

then I only want one entry to be kept in the `XML` file :

**For the above example:** the `txtUserid=2` and `textPassword=m`

The code:

```
XDocument Xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Users"));
if (System.IO.File.Exists("D:\\Users.xml"))
{
   Xdoc = XDocument.Load("D:\\Users.xml");
}
else
{
   Xdoc = new XDocument();
}

XElement xml = new XElement("Users",
               new XElement("User",
               new XAttribute("UserId", txtUserName.Text),
               new XAttribute("Password", txtPassword.Text)));

if (Xdoc.Descendants().Count() > 0)
{
   Xdoc.Descendants().First().Add(xml);
}
else
{
   Xdoc.Add(xml);
}

Xdoc.Save("D:\\Users.xml");
```

Comment: Don't save passwords in plain-text in an xml file.

Comment: I canot do code details at the moment, but the easiest way is to remove any existing user nodes before creating new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Search your existing XML document for a node where the UserId attribute matches your current one, and if it does, modify that one, else make a new one.

I'd imagine that your coude would resemble the following:

```
        List<XElement> list = Xdoc.Descendants("User").Where(el => el.Attribute("UserId").Value == txtUserName.Text).ToList();
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            // Add new node
        }
        else
        {
            // Modify the existing node
        }
```

Edit: In response to your comment, the code to edit your XElement would look something like

```
string myValue = "myValue";
list.First().Attribute("ElementName").SetValue(myValue);
```

Comment: How to write the code for modifying existing node??I m new to C#

Answer (score 0):

Writing textbox values to XML file in C#

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    // Open the XML doc  
    System.Xml.XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    myXmlDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("InsertData.xml"));
    System.Xml.XmlNode myXmlNode = myXmlDocument.DocumentElement.FirstChild;

    // Create new XML element and populate its attributes  
    System.Xml.XmlElement myXmlElement = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("entry");
    myXmlElement.SetAttribute("Userid", Server.HtmlEncode(textUserid.Text));
    myXmlElement.SetAttribute("Username", Server.HtmlEncode(textUsername.Text));
    myXmlElement.SetAttribute("AccountNo", Server.HtmlEncode(txtAccountNo.Text));
    myXmlElement.SetAttribute("BillAmount", Server.HtmlEncode(txtBillAmount.Text));


    // Insert data into the XML doc and save  
    myXmlDocument.DocumentElement.InsertBefore(myXmlElement, myXmlNode);
    myXmlDocument.Save(Server.MapPath("InsertData.xml"));

    // Re-bind data since the doc has been added to  
    BindData();


    Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Record inserted Successfully Inside the XML File....')</script>");
    textUserid.Text = "";
    textUsername.Text = "";
    txtAccountNo.Text = "";
    txtBillAmount.Text = "";  
}

void BindData()
{
    XmlTextReader myXmlReader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("InsertData.xml"));
    myXmlReader.Close();
}
```

Comment: there is no check for existing user with the same login in the XML however OP asked exactly about this `I dont want the same txtuserid values to be written twice in xml `. Please check `XElement` `XDocument` from  System.Linq.Xml also - it is more convenient than `XmlDocument`. At least you do not have to encode values